# length of string across multiple columns, get length difference for each row

Tags: r, dplyr

```
data = tibble(x = c("a", "b"), y = c("aa", "b"), z = c("a", "bb"))

data %>% 
  mutate(str_length = across(c(x, y, z), ~ str_count(., ".")))
```

How do I calculate the difference between str_length for each row?

Desired output would be: `data$str_diff` = c(1, 1).

Comment: What do you mean by difference when you have more than two elements?

Comment: Right...I want to calculate the difference between the range of all values in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `tidyverse`, with `pmap`:

```r
data %>% 
  mutate(str_diff = pmap_int(across(x:z), ~ diff(range(str_length(c(...))))))

# A tibble: 2 × 4
  x     y     z     str_diff
  <chr> <chr> <chr>    <int>
1 a     aa    a            1
2 b     b     bb           1
```

Comment: I do not understand; the difference of str_length of row1 and row2 is 0?!. Maybe you could comment @Maël. Many thanks!

Comment: I notice now, it should be `str_length`, not `str_count`. This computes the rowwise difference of the range of length of each columns.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
data %>% 
  mutate(
    str_diff = abs(str_count(x) - str_count(y))
  )
```

```
 x     y         z str_diff
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>    <int>
1 a     aa        1        1
2 b     b         2        0
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to do this with multiple rows so that I get the abs difference in the range of all values for each row?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```r
data$str_diff <- apply(sapply(data, nchar), 1, function(row) diff(range(row)))
```

Which can be shortened to use only one `*apply`:

```r
data$str_diff <- apply(data, 1, function(row) diff(range(nchar(row))))
```

Answer (score 1):

a dplyr solution:

```
data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(str_diff = diff(range(map(c(x, y, z), str_count))))
```